# How to deal with 'Why are you asking this?' type of comments

Tags: discussion

*** EDIT: Thanks for the comments, the misusing terms on "answer" and "comment" are corrected ***

I have a returning problem about how to prevent in a polite and efficient way the "Why are you asking this" type of comments.

My opinion that this kind of comments:

- decreasing the quality of the site's knowledge base,
- discouraging the askers,
- and mislead the potential future answerers, so lowering the chance that others manage to develop a real answer.

Yes I know that there are stupid questions. I am not talking about these. Just to get you a short example I've asked about how to *prevent* a *handled* exception when calling a method in a library, and spent at least 15 mins to describe the scenario as focused as I can, and got comment "So the exception is handled? Where's your problem, then?". What's more: this comment upvoted later twice...

** Edited based on the comments about XY problem: I think this is definitely not an XY problem. Asking how to prevent an exception, does not need to describe that the problem is that exception is threwing. So it is correct to ask "how to prevent" and incorrect to as Why I am would like to prevent. (Because it is thrown) **

So as a summary: 1) The commenter got points. 2) I had lowered chance to get an answer. 3) I was forced to invest (unnecessary) extra work to answer the comment and explain the obvious, and and what is more important_not_ *question* *related* *base* *knowledge* to the person who was intended to help me. Clearly something is not working here...

- asking in this case back holds the message that you are not competent even for the question level (not the answer level)
- the clear sign of lack of wanting help to the other person, and/or the disrespect.
- asking back a short "Why..." is a cheap way to get reputation point with no work, and forcing the person who ask spending more time to answer to an irrevelant and out of focus thing.

My problem here if I try to prevent this, and explain my whole life in the original question then the question will be so unfocused and boring and lower quqlity. Is not it a realistic presumption that in question about a quite complex but well known library both the asker both the commenter knows why it has more benefits to prevent an exception and not just catch and handle it.

I am really wondering how to handle this, both in the question, and both after the the "Why ..." comment arrived.

I know that would be an obvious joke to ask me why I am asking this :-), but in case you would like to write a joke try something completely different, that was *my* joke.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to have a link to the question that you're talking about?

Comment: sloth (35k) asked that in a comment not an answer.  since so many questions are XY Problems, it seems valid to ask.

Comment: See also: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163250).

Comment: some users **like** knowing that they can abandon their ill advised pursuit of **Y** and welcome a better solution for **X** and amend the scope of the question when they learn of an alterative

Comment: We should not have to scan your profile to know [what question you're talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608457/how-to-configure-roslyn-customworkspace-not-to-cry-for-visual-basic)...

Comment: @Cupcake I prefer not. The point of my question is increasing quality and efficiency not complaining about a person.

Comment: XY: `1) The commenter got points` comments do not earn points

Comment: @g.pickardou ok, that's fair enough. In the future, please consider just copying and pasting the answer that you got so that people have more context, although I can understand if you would prefer not to do that too.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I rolled back [because the original poster stated that he or she prefers not to link to the original context](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254536/how-to-deal-with-why-are-you-asking-this-type-of-comments#comment19426_254536).

Comment: I think this is definitely not an XY problem. Asking how to prevent an exception, does not need to describe that the problem is that exception is threwing. So it is correct to ask "how to prevent" and incorrect to as Why I am would like to prevent. Because it is thrown.

Comment: @Plutonix: I mean when the comment flagged as "adding something useful"

Comment: even upvoted comments do not earn points; it just means some other reader agrees with the sentiment/text/idea expressed

Comment: @Plutonix: my disinformation, sorry.

Comment: Maybe your specific problem isn't an XY problem. But you say you don't want to share your specific problem, and want a general answer. Are you sure **this** question isn't an XY problem?

Answer (score 17):

An *answer* that simply asks questions of the question author isn't an answer, and should be flagged as Not an Answer.

A comment that is asking the author why they are asking the question can often be a *great* comment.  In many cases it's important to understand some additional context to the question for it to be answered.  There may be many avenues of approaching the problem and a greater content may well be needed to understand which is best.

These types of comments are also how one deals with [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163250), in which someone is asking for an solution to a technical problem that won't help them solve their *actual* problem.  Ensuring that the question they are asking will actually help them solve their actual underlying problem is being *very helpful* to the question author.  No doing this, and giving a solution to a problem that won't help the author solve their *actual* problem is not *nearly* as helpful as taking the time to determine the real problem and solve it.  In some cases providing such a solution can be actively harmful.

If you don't wish to provide the additional content of your question when someone asks you about it, it is of course up to you whether or not you answer.  Sometimes the additional context *isn't* useful, perhaps it would simply be distracting, or just a whole lot of work that is unnecessary.  If you feel that the context won't be helpful, you are of course free to not answer such clarifying questions.  If the question is in fact answerable without the context, then you might not get as good of an answer, but you can still get an answer.  In other cases, understanding the context doesn't just help to provide a *better* answer, but it is needed to provide *any* answer.  In such cases your question may end up being closed until you edit it to include sufficient information for it to be answerable.

Comment: Except it is obvious base knowledge. Asking why is a problem an exception is throwing (even internally), and why I would like to prevent it si not great, because this falls to a category of obvious base knowledge.

Comment: @g.pickardou: a) Not everything is obvious to everyone, and if one person is wondering it is likely others are as well. b) I can't count how many times an asker thought something was obvious and it turned out they were incorrect. For example, [this asker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867075/variable-nesting-in-python) responded to "Why don't you use a list" with the somewhat misguided "i know the difference between a list and a variable, i need a variable"

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Sure _obvious_ is a relative term. But I think talking about deep C# or Java question, when I am asking how to prevent an exception it not constructive to ask "So the exception is handled? Where's your problem, then"

Comment: @g.pickardou As I said, if you feel that no more context is needed, then not answering the clarifying question is your decision.  Sometimes the clarifying question *doesn't* make sense and *doesn't* need to be answered.  However, if the question makes no sense at all, consider the possibility that you don't understand it, and that the question is asking something else, such as what task are you trying to perform that is generating an exception.

Comment: Maybe the original asker did not have a good reason to do what they are trying (XY problem), but maybe I have a reason to do this and actually want the answer to the question.  Finding answers that say "Why are you doing this; you're doing it wrong" are absolutely not helpful.  Phrasing the answer in such a way as "You could do the thing you are asking this way, but maybe a better approach is this" is more respectful to the asker and more helpful to later searchers.

Comment: @FazJaxton When someone is actually don't something wrong, telling them that they're doing it wrong *is enormously helpful*.  Knowing when you're trying to do something inappropriate is very important, otherwise you might figure out how to do the inappropriate thing and run into all sorts of problem.

Comment: Additionally, the whole point of this meta question is it's asking about cases where you don't have enough context to judge if the question asked is an appropriate solution for the underlying problem or not because you don't know the underlying problem, so you *can't* just suggest the appropriate solution and not tell them that the solution they're attempting is inappropriate and harmful because *you don't know the underlying problem,*, as that's the whole premise here.

Answer (score 2):

These aren't answers and should be down-voted and/or flagged for moderator attention.

At best they should be comments - but there are far more constructive ways of asking the OP for more information to clarify the question.